# Steps of generating breadcrumbs in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I analyse the "Mage_Page_Block_Html_Breadcrumbs" Breadcrumb.php, but i don't understand how it's creating the breadcrumb, where it is getting the link and title of the category?

1. How it's creating?
2. How we can show category Id along with category name?
3. Any one have batter explanation about it?

Suggestion will be realy appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

Every action of controller adds a crumb in this way:

```
$this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('reports')->__('Sales'), Mage::helper('reports')->__('Sales'));
```

For the catalog category context, there's a Block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs`
that calls `Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data->getBreadcrumbPath()`

There's no event dispatched, so... I would rewrite the Helper class.

If you want to use observers, instead, I think that's possible to observe the prepare layout, and before the preparelayout of `Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs` you could remove all crumb and redefine them.

Comment: Gaspardo Webfor i got that helper function, but where you find this '$this->_addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('reports')->('Sales'), Mage::helper('reports')->('Sales'));'

For the catalog category context, ther's a Block "Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs" that calls "Mage_Catalog_Helper_Data->getBreadcrumbPath" can you please give me more details about it

Comment: This was an example:
addBreadcrumb(Mage::helper('reports')->('Sales'), Mage::helper('reports')->('Sales'));


Look in Mage_Catalog_Block_Breadcrumbs:
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Breadcrumbs.php

in protected function _prepareLayout()

You can see how the catalog page builds their own Breadcrumbs:

$path  = Mage::helper('catalog')->getBreadcrumbPath();

    foreach ($path as $name => $breadcrumb) {
        $breadcrumbsBlock->addCrumb($name, $breadcrumb);
        $title[] = $breadcrumb['label'];
    }

Comment: Yes that is right, but hwo magento come to know to get data from helper, some thing must be there, where it tells magento to look into the helper getBreadcrumbPath() method

Comment: I think here:

In Mage_Catalog_Block_Category_View:
    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        $this->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/breadcrumbs');
    }